# Cannot change slider position Corona

Tags: lua, widget, slider, coronasdk

I have the weirdest behaviour of a Corona slider widget. It is defined as

```
local slider = widget.newSlider
{
    top = 100,
    left = 100,
    anchorX = 0,
    anchorY = 0,
    width = 200,
    value = 1
}
```

The slider is correctly added to the point (100, 100). However, if I check the top value it will give me `nil`.
I tried to change the position of the slider by using

```
slider.top = 300
```

which should move the slider so that it is located at (100, 300). The slider is however still shown at (100, 100), but now `slider.top` returns 300. The same thing applies to `slider.left`, but `slider.width` seems to work fine. Why can't I access the `top`and `left`properties of the widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the position of the slider, try changing the top and left values inside the parameters, else other way to do is,

```
local slider = widget.newSlider
{
  top = 100,
  left = 100,
  anchorX = 0,
  anchorY = 0,
  width = 200,
  value = 1
}
slider.x = 300
This will definitely change the position.
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! The left and top seems to be initializers and not attributes.